# Scale background image to element size

Tags: html, css, scale

I am trying to have a circular image that scales to fit. I have tried the following code and the circle scales but my image doesn't scale with it. The only way the image will show inside the circle is if I put the image in as a background URL. Perhaps someone could point me in the right direction. Here is the code:

**HTML**

```
<div id="circlePicHolder" class="circularImageHolder">
      <div class="circularImage"></div>
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
.circularImageHolder{
     width: 100%;
     height:100%;
     padding-top:5%;
 }

 .circularImage{
        width: 100%;
        padding-bottom: 100%;
        height:0;
        background-image:url('college.gif');
        background-color:white;
        border: 1px solid red;
        margin:0 auto;
       -webkit-border-radius: 50%;
       -moz-border-radius: 50%;
       border-radius: 50%;
}

.circularImage img{
     max-width:100%;
     max-height:100%;
}
```

Thanks.

Comment: Could you post the code (with css) with the img that you tried which did not work?

Comment: Here is a fiddle of what I mean. You will notice that the circle scales downwards but crops the image as it does so. I need the image to resize with the circle. http://jsfiddle.net/U5LLW/

Comment: See my answer for bg image

Comment: Would those who marked the question down like to explain why they did so?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can apply

```
.circularImage{
    ...
    background-size: 100% 100%;
    ...
}
```

This way the background image scales as you resize

http://jsfiddle.net/U5LLW/1/

OR if you want to use an image, you need to make sure to apply overflow hidden or the image will not be inside of your border radius

http://jsfiddle.net/U5LLW/3/

```
.circularImage{
    overflow: hidden;
    border: 1px solid red;
    margin:0 auto;
    -webkit-border-radius: 50%;
    -moz-border-radius: 50%;
    border-radius: 50%;
}

.circularImage img{
    width: 100%;
}
```

The `img` should be width 100%, if you only use max-width then when the container's size exceed the image size, the image will not get any bigger. Max-width does work if you make the container smaller but not larger

Comment: Thanks. I have tried both methods. The first works. For some reason the second produces an oval shape when I need circular.

Comment: @Inkers it produces the oval shape because the image I used is not a square. If you use a square image then it will be a circle. Also you can use whatever image format you want as long as it meets your need, there is no best answer for it as it is opinion based. You should probably removed that line from the question for the question to stay open

Answer (score 3):

Set your image to 100% width, then you can put the image itself inside `circlePicHolder`. You have to set a wdith of 100% for `.circularImage` otherwise it never will be "responsive". Of course you can use the background-image method, but there's not really any specific need to unless your design requires it.

```
<div id="circlePicHolder" class="circularImageHolder">
    <img src="/url.png">
</div>

.circularImageHolder{
     width: 100%;
     height:100%;
     padding-top:5%;
     text-align: center;
 }
.circularImageHolder img{
    width: 100%;
    height: 200px;
    width: 200px;
    border-radius: 50%;
    -moz-border-radius: 50%;
    -webkit-border-radius: 50%;
    border: 1px solid red;
}
```

Keep in mind, your image height and widths must be equal in order to achieve this effect in this particular method of CSS, so for example see this jsfiddle; http://jsfiddle.net/RwmGQ/2/

Comment: My image doesn't show when I use this method. The red border shows me a circular shape but the image doesn't show within. If I apply a height to the img, then the shape becomes oval.

Comment: Check the updated code above along with jsfiddle. In order for it to be truly round, you need the image to have an equal aspect ratio - otherwise you won't be able to use border-radius to achieve this effect.